# Sending GZipped data to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I understand that SQL Server uses GZip for COMPRESS/DECOMPRESS. I've read, that the data is stored in SQL Server as hex and adds extra characters to the beginning.

It must be possible to send and receive compressed data to and from SQL Server. My case relates to large JSON payloads, however this would be applicable to importing large amounts of structured data from CSV/XML as well.

**Stored procedure**:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE gzipTest
    @compressed VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    SELECT CAST(DECOMPRESS(@compressed) as VARCHAR(MAX)) as json
END;
```

**Example Code**:

```
mssql.exec({
    data: {
        compressed: {
            type: Datalayer.sql.VarBinary(Datalayer.sql.MAX),
            value: deflateSync(json),
        },
    },
    spName: 'gzipTest',
})
```

A co-worker found this example code, for receiving compressed data:

- https://jsfiddle.net/58mgsy9a/

However iterating over the zip file buffer `array.map(pair => parseInt(pair, 16))` seems like way too much processing for something that should adhere to standards on both sides.

Comment: "My case relates to large JSON payloads" - shred into relational columns......

Comment: Seems like you trying to invent multiple wheels here... why not use the correct tools for the job?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you saying you want to send compressed data to SQL, store it in that native format, then decompress and use that data within SQL?

Comment: Re use the right tools for the job. While the OPENJSON operations perform satisfactorily, it's clear that both the mssql native driver and tedious javascript driver struggle sending large json blobs.

Sending data in table format performs incredibly poorly.  Calling update, insert statements either in batch, sequentially or  in parallel is worse.  Currently to most performant approach has been to send the data at the end of all processing, as a JSON  payload.

The bottleneck right now, is the tedious/native driver processing the buffer as it goes to/from SQL Server.

Comment: You seem to be conflating storage format with presentation format. `COMPRESS`ed output is `varbinary(max)` and is stored in SQL Server as binary data. It is only presented in SSMS and other tools as a hexadecimal literal with a `0x` prefix so that it's some kind of "human readable." Does this question have a question?

Comment: Also worth pointing out: **deflate** is a compression codec described in [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951). **gzip** is a file format described in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952). They're not the same thing. Deflate is one of the compression schemes that gzip can use, but a gzip stream adds a header and footer around the compressed data stream. If you want to do something that adheres to standards on both sides then try using SQL Server's `COMPRESS` and `DECOMPRESS` functions in conjunction with the `zlib.gzip()` and `zlib.gunzip()` functions in NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks we are making way more progress with zlib.gzip. Will see f the overheads of compression are compensated by transmission savings